# Norm of a matrix formed using a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose, $ A $ is a unitary matrix in $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $ given by $ (a_{i,j})_{1\le i,j\le n} $ which has the property that, for all the basis elements $ e_i $, $ Ae_i\ne \lambda e_j $ for all $i,j $ and $ |\lambda|=1 $. Then consider the matrix $ B=(a_{i,j}^4)_{1\le i,j\le n} $. Then is it true that $ ||B||< 1 $?

I could prove that, $ ||B||\le 1 $, but I want to know if its strictly less than 1 in this case.

Comment: Consider the unitary matrix $A=\lambda Id$ such that $\lambda^4=1$. Notice that $B=Id$.

Comment: $\|B\| < 1$ only if all the column vectors of $A$ have more than one non-zero entry, hence if $|(Ae_i)_k| \ne 1$ for every $i,k$ (you can write it $|A e_i| \ne e_j$)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wanted to write, $ Ae_i\ne \lambda e_j $ for all $ |\lambda|=1 $.

Comment: I asked this question in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/235553/norm-of-an-operator-formed-using-a-unitary-operator . It has been answered there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof for $ ||B||\le 1$(This still doesn't answer the question):-
Consider the vector space $ \mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^n$.
There consider the subspace spanned by $ e_i^{\otimes 4} $. Then $ e_i^{\otimes 4} $ forms a orthonormal basis for this subspace. And the matrix for $ A\otimes A\otimes A\otimes A$ restricted to this subspace wrt this basis is exactly $ B $. And we know that $ ||A^{\otimes 4}||=||A||^4=1 $. So $ ||B||\le 1$.

Comment: Note you cannot restrict $A^{\otimes 4}$ on that subspace. You have $A^{\otimes 4} e_i^{\otimes 4} =\sum_{j_1,..,j_4} a_{j_1,i_1}..a_{j_4,i_4} e_{j_1}\otimes .. \otimes e_{j_4}$ which usually does not lie in that subspace. But here if you compose $A^{\otimes 4}$ with the orthogonal projection on the subspace then it works and the matrix coefficients of that map are indeed those of $B$.

Comment: By restriction, I meant compression, which is what you mentioned.